# Is there a way to pull inline images from gmail using python?

Tags: python, image, gmail, imap

Is there a way to pull inline images from an email within gmail to save somewhere? If not, is there a way to get the image url  of the inline image?

Would IMAP or POP support this?

I've been able to pull an email via IMAP, but I can't find any trace of the inline images within the email, unless the image has been converted to strings of letters and numbers. I did a search for the image url, and couldn't find that in the resulting string either, so I'm not sure if it's possible to pull inline images from gmail.

Answer (score 1):

If you can successfully pull the mail from gmail via POP3 or IMAP. Then you'll find the image maybe encoded into BASE64 string.

All you need to do is parse the image part and decode it to binary.

The following maybe useful:

- [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)
- [Email in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html)